# Drawing a Checkbox In a Table For a Question

Tags: support, tables

How can I put ***checkbox column*** in a table in a question?

for example:

| car name | Option1(checkbox - yes/no) |
| --- | --- |
| a | yes |
| b | no |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only by mimicking / trickery, for example:

| car name | Option1(checkbox - yes/no) |
| --- | --- |
| a | <kbd>X</kbd> |
| b |  |

Use keyboard HTML tags `<kbd>X</kbd>`.

Or use the Unicode chars, for example ✅

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#HTML for more options (hat tip to JG)

There is no option to use true HTML [input tag with its type set to 'checkbox'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

See also [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: In theory could also abuse unicode/emoji checkboxes I suspect

Comment: @rene Thanks,like you i think there is no other way to checkbox simulation for stackoverflow